# Ratios - Determining proportions/quantities

Tags: linear-algebra, ratio

`x : y = 8:5`

Say I subtract a value of 400 from `x` and 300 from `y`, so that:

`x-400 : y-300 = 8:3`

How do I determine the value of `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cross multiply the ratios to get $5x=8y, 3(x-400)=8(y-300)$.  Now solve the first equation for one of the variables, plug that into the second and you have one equation in one variable.  In this case it will be linear.